# Invisible File Input element doesn't work with javascript

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I trying to get a better looking file input form element with bootstrap using a invisible element [example](http://duckranger.com/2012/06/pretty-file-input-field-in-bootstrap/) with a code (simplified) like:

```
<div class="container">
  <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
    <input class="hide" id="filesel" type="file" />
    <div class="input-append">
      <input id="filename" class="input-large" type="text" />
      <a class="btn" onclick="testFun();">Browse</a>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $('input[id=filesel]').change(function() {
  $('#filename').val($(this).val());
  });

  function testFun(){
  inp = $("#filesel").click();
  }
</script>
```

But it doesn't work as expected. If I remove the `hide` class to the file input tag, it works. How can i solve it?

**UPDATE 1:** Tested with more navigators:

- Ubuntu Chromium  18.0 -> Fails
- Ubuntu Firefox   16.0 -> Works

My in Chromium the `hide` or `style="display: none"` affects also the File Browse window.

Comment: what is linked to your `hide` class ? js actions ? css ?

Comment: also note that not all browsers return a value for a file input field. So plan on this failing in browsers like IE. And some browsers dont let you simulate a click on a file input control as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setting `display:none;` won't work on file input. Although you can set `visibility:hidden;` or `opacity:0;`
There is also a nice tutorial about styling file inputs [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/inputfile.html)

Comment: Good with `style="position: absolute; visibility: hidden;"/` I get it working.

Answer (score 1):

What happens if you remove your `hide` class, and add `style="display: none"` (as per the example) ?